# windows cmd attrib -s -h -r i:\*.* /s /d

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, usb-drive

My pen drive was corrupted and I came across the above command to retrieve back the data. However, when I run this command

```
attrib -s -h -r i:\*.* /s /d
```

My drive name and all its contents (folders & files) name were changed to special characters. I really need help on how to change this back to normal

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

Check whether the files are not in hidden mode. Follow the following steps

## Step 1:

[Download *AutorunExterminator*](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-11613-autorun-exterminator), extract it → double-click on "AutorunExterminator" → plug your flash drive now.

This will remove the `autorun.inf` files from your flash drive and also from drives.

**Note:** Make sure .NET Framework is installed in your PC to install the AutorunExterminator or [click here to download the .NET Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19)

## Step 2:

Click "Start", type cmd, right-click on the cmd.exe result and select "Run as administrator". Now the command prompt will be opened.

Here I assume your flash drive as G:

Enter this command.

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
```

You can copy the above command → right-click in the Command Prompt and paste it.

**Note:** Replace the letter `g` with your flash drive letter.

Now check for your files in Flash Drive.

## Step 3:

After that, [download the Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-105-malwarebytes-anti-malware), update it → Perform "Full Scan"

**Note:** Default selected option is "Quick Scan".

Good Luck.

collected this data from http://ccm.net/forum/affich-654245-how-to-recover-my-pendrive-data

Comment: Chkdsk /f <pendrive> will help in addition to repair logical errors.